# File extension coloring in fish shell

Tags: shell, unix, fish

Is there a way to color code specific file extensions in the fish shell?

For example, if I ran the following command, I would want python files to appear a certain color and javascript files to appear a different color:

```
$ ls

file.py  # this would display as green for example
file.js  # this would display as yellow
```

I've been able to fully customize just about everything else but I can't figure out if there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't done by fish. It's done by the `ls` command. See the description of the `LSCOLORS` env var in `man ls`. I'm not aware of any `ls` implementation that allows you to customize the color based on the file extension. There may be third-party tools that you can pipe the output of `ls` through that will do what you want but I can't think of one off the top of my head.